# How to send an email with data input options?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am a newbie to coding..
I just want to know if there is anyway that we can send an email through Gmail with an option to select and enter data by the users and then save the selected choices in google sheets...

e.g i would like to ask these details from the clients and then save them in googlesheet. It shouldn't lead to an external link but the interface should open up in email itself..

e.g
Hello there,
Please fill in the following details
[image]

Can anyone please helpme with it...

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a Google form, request they open and fill out. If the form collects email that is handy. Responses to Google forms are collected to a spreadsheet. I don't know about in or out of organization or other issues this might encounter.